# Responsive Slider positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a responsive website but i'm struggling with the dots of the slideshow as you see in the picture below which is when I toggle to the device toolbar they change their place i have tried everything that comes in my mind from the relative units to the absolute ones but nothing worked please I need help with that, i searched around in google and so on but i didn't find anything helpful.

[image]

when I toggle to the **device toolbar**:

[image]

as you notice the position of the dots changes i don't want this behaviour.

this is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EatManger</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="query.css">

</head>

<body style="background-color:purple">


  <div class="container">

    <div class="logo-box">
      <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars hamburger-btn"></i>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">services</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">reservation</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">menu</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">our chefs</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">events</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade-zz">
      <img src="images/food3.png" class="imgSlide">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade-zz">
      <img src="images/pizza.png" class="imgSlide" >
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade-zz">
      <img src="images/hamburger2.png" class="imgSlide">
    </div>

    <div class="dotz">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1-1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2-1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3-1)"></span>
    </div>


  </div>





  <div class="contact-box">
    <div class="adress">
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt conbox"></i>
      <h3 class="contact-title">Address</h3>
      <p class="contact-description">4579 Penn Street,Manchester<br>united kingdom</p>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <i class="fas fa-phone-volume conbox"></i>
      <h3 class="contact-title">Phone</h3>
      <p class="contact-description">636-399-9776 <br> 573-225-7350</p>
    </div>
    <div class="opening-time">
      <i class="far fa-clock conbox"></i>
      <h3 class="contact-title">Opening time</h3>
      <p class="contact-description">all the days of the week <br>from 6 am to midnight</p>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="about-us">
<i class="fas fa-utensils abicon"></i>
<h1 class="title">About us</h1>
  <p class="title-description">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un
    imprimeur
    anonyme assembla </p>
</section>

















  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height .1s;
}

.container-add{
  height: 20rem;
}

.hamburger-btn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 4px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.logo-box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 15.62rem;
  align-items: center;
visibility: hidden;
}

.main-nav-hide{
  visibility:visible;
}

.main-nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  /* display: none; */
}



.main-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 20px;
}


.slideshow-container{
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.imgSlide{
  width: 100%;
}

.imgSlide-show{
  display: block;
}

.dotz{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50vw
}

.dot{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd
}

.active{
background-color: #ff9900;

}

.active:hover,.dot:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fade-zz{
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  transition:.4s
}

@keyframes fade {
  from{
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to{
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.contact-box{
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.39rem;
  height: 380px;
}

.conbox{
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* margin-top: .8rem; */
}


.adress{
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: roboto;
margin-bottom: 3rem;
position: relative;
top: .5rem;
}


.phone{
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: roboto;
margin-bottom: .8rem;
}


.opening-time{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}


.about-us{
  color: white;
}

.title{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.abicon{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
padding-right: 7rem;
margin-top: 1rem;
font-size: 2rem;
position: relative;
top: 2%;
}

.title-description{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//HAMBURGER BUTTON

var hamBtn=document.querySelector(".hamburger-btn");

hamBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.querySelector(".main-nav").classList.toggle("main-nav-hide");
document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("container-add");



});


//SLIDESHOW

slideIndex=0;

function currentSlide(n){
  slideIndex=n;
  showSlide(slideIndex);
}

function showSlide(n){
  var i;
  var slides=document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
console.log(slides);
  var dots=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display="none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex>slides.length) {
  slideIndex=1;
}
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
setTimeout(showSlide,50)

setInterval(showSlide,6000)
```

sorry about the question title i couldn't come up with a better one describing my situation any suggestion for a better title would be accepted to help other people who are struggling from the same problem find the solution and thank youu in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add to ".dotz" the following

```
.dotz{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

To center any block has `position:absolute` you just need to  `left, right` to 0 and `margin` to auto and for sure the parent div has to have  `position:relative`